# SuSE Tumbleweed -X fails to start after running zypper dup

Tags: xorg, kde, opensuse, gui

Used Zypper dup to upgrade to Tumbleweed 20210311 (kernel 5.11.4-1), after reboot, screen shows Tumbleweed logo, BUT boots to CLI login.

Neither X nor KDE starts.

Cursory exam of `/var/log/zypper.log` didn't show any problems (but given volume of data may have missed something), but checking Xorg.log shows (at 1297.567)

```
"Failed to initialize GLX extension (compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)".
```

System worked fine with 5.10.x series of kernels, but no GUI with 5.11 series of kernels.

Zypper erased kernel default -5.10.16-1.2.x86_64, so can't fall back to older kernel.  Suspect that NVIDIA drivers were not retrieved/loaded, but not sure how to rectify problem

Checked `/var/log/messages` and for 2021-03-03 PackageKit was successful and
`plasma-pk-updates` finished successfully.

tarting 2021-03-08 showed

`PK error  packman "repo-not-available" and "plasma-pk-updates" failed`

Would greatly appreciate either suggestions for further trouble shooting or a solution to get GUI working again

Thanks